# When should use the word "causation" versus "causality"?

Tags: terminology, causality

Today, I read a couple of discussions in Cross Validated, and these two words popped up quite a bit. I do not know how to differentiate them in usage (especially writing) because they are quite interchangeable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In statistical contexts, they’re interchangeable. (See, e.g.  [*Causality (also referred to as causation, or cause and effect)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) and [*Causation (Alternative titles: causality, cause and effect)*](https://www.britannica.com/topic/causation).)

Usually the “right answer” for a given context comes from an ossified expression like “correlation is not causation” or “Granger causality”.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I am asking others about the meaning of the phrase "ossified expression".

Comment: A technical term for what I meant would be [collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation).